# How to show '0' amount for a month, if no data exists in the table for that month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables Costtable (Id,ResourceId, Amount,Date) and
 ResourceTable (ResourceId,Name) which shows output as below.

[image]

I want to show 0 amount  for rest of the name in case of September. For e.g. if rest of the Resources does not appear in cost table they should appear 0 in amount

My Desired output

[image]

My current query

```
SELECT
    RG.Id AS Id,
    RG.Name AS Name,
    ISNULL(SUM(AC.Amount), 0) AS Amount,
    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), AC.[Date], 105), 7) AS [YearMonth]
FROM 
    Cost AS AC
    INNER JOIN Resource AS RG ON AC.ResourceGroupId = RG.Id
WHERE 
    AC.PortalId = '100' AND 
    [Date] >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(m, -11, GETDATE())), 0)
GROUP BY 
    RG.Name, 
    RG.Id, 
    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), AC.[Date], 105), 7)
ORDER BY 
    RG.Name DESC
```

Comment: If you need to work with dates / months, you should create a date table, either one with row per day or maybe also one with row per month. It's a lot easier to create the missing rows when joining your costs with a calendar

Comment: What result you get for above query?

Comment: The first output which i have given from my query

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `cross join` and `left join`.  Your question is hard to follow because your tables and descriptions differ.  However, this is the idea:

```
select t.minid, t.name, ym.yearmonth, coalesce(amount, 0) as amount
from (select name, min(id) as minid from t group by name) n cross join
     (select distinct yearmonth from t) ym left join
     t
     on t.name = n.name and t.yearmonth = ym.yearmonth;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying i tried that but not working for me.. i have added my curent query in question

Comment: Actually i am unable to replcate/rewrite ur query with mine

Comment: @user1037747 . . . Put your query into a CTE and then try this query.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a FULL JOIN instead of a innerjoin only.

That should do the trick.